# how to view blob content

Tags: java, blob

JavaBean has some field type of byte[].

Bean is stored in DB to BLOB type of column.

I know that it is XML message.

How can I see this XML message.

thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Convert those bytes to characters. You only need to know the character encoding beforehand, otherwise those characters will end up like [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

Here's an example using `String` constructor and UTF-8 character encoding:

```
String string = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for so fast response :)

Comment: REsultSet rs...

Blob blob = rs.getBlob();
...

bytes[] bytes =  blob.getBytes;

String string = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");

Comment: Behind each comment, there's an `edit` link (and a `delete` button). Please make use of it instead of spamming with a lot of comments in short time :) As to your question: what exactly is the problem when you do that? Or haven't you tried it at all? Do it first.